# Compare CreationTime and user input

Tags: powershell

Im trying to make a program find all the files created on a certain date. How do I make the input from the user the same format so both can be compared?

Thanks for the help.

```
$root= [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
Write-Host "Programa de reenvío a unbilling." -fore white
$fecha = Read-Host -Prompt 'Colocar fecha que desea enviar. FORMATO DD/mm/YY. Ejemplo 31/12/2018 '
Get-ChildItem "$root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\" -Filter *.txt | Where-Object CreationTime -EQ ([DateTime]::Parse($fecha))

    Foreach-Object {
    $archivo= $_.Name
    Write-Host "Facturas encontrada: $archivo " -fore green
    #start-process -filepath "$root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\$archivo" -verb print | out-printer "UNBILLING" 

    }
```

Comment: [graphical date picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/creating-a-graphical-date-picker?view=powershell-6)

Comment: this is the link i meant to post http://www.ultimaforsan.com/logs/2013/5/16/powershell-date-picker.html

Comment: As written, your problem is that you're using `-eq` to compare filesystem timestamps that have time-of-day components to calendar-day-only timestamps (_no_ time-of-day components). Formatting only comes into play with respect to whether `[DateTime]::Parse()` can recognize the user input - providing GUI helpers for the user to pick a date is a separate issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A graphical date picker doesn't require the user to enter a special format,
here a quite condensed year calendar function with weeks and week days.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\12\07\SO_53661152.ps1
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
Function Pick-Date {
  $Cal = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar
  $Cal.ShowWeekNumbers = $true
  $Cal.MaxSelectionCount = 1
  $Cal.Dock = 'Fill'
  $Form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
  $Form.text = "Colocar fecha que desea enviar. [enter]"
  $Form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(656,620)
  $btnSelect = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $btnSelect.Size = "100,100"
  $btnSelect.add_Click({ $Form.close() })
  $btnSelect.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(530,480)
  $btnSelect.Text="ENTER"
  $Form.Controls.Add($btnSelect )
  $Form.AcceptButton = $btnSelect
  $Form.Controls.Add($Cal)
  $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
  [void]$Form.ShowDialog()
  return (Get-Date($Cal.SelectionStart))
}

$root= [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
Write-Host "Programa de reenvío a unbilling." -fore white

$fecha = Pick-Date

Get-ChildItem "$root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\" -Filter *.txt | 
  Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Date -EQ $fecha} | Foreach-Object {
    $archivo = $_.Name
    Write-Host "Facturas encontrada: $archivo " -fore green
    #start-process -filepath "$root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\$archivo" -verb print | out-printer "UNBILLING" 
}
```

Monthnames, first week, first day of week depend on locale/user settings.

[image]

Comment: Weird... I cant access the objects name. If I use $archivo = $_.Name in the code

Get-ChildItem "$root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\" -Filter *.txt | 
  Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Date -EQ $fecha | Foreach-Object {
    $archivo = $_.Name
    Write-Host "Facturas encontrada: $archivo " -fore green
    #start-process -filepath "$root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\$archivo" -verb print | out-printer "UNBILLING" 
    }
}

Comment: Sorry, there was a closing `}` missing in the `Where-Object`,changed above.

Answer (score 1):

**Date *formats* are incidental to your problem**: as long as `[DateTime]::Parse($fecha)` succeeds in converting the user's input to a`[datetime]` instance, .NET's date/time arithmetic will work as expected (and providing a GUI method for the user to pick a date may be helpful, but is similarly incidental to the problem at hand).

**The real problem is that the `*Time*` properties** on `[System.IO.FileInfo]` and `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instances output by `Get-ChildItem` are *specific points in time*, meaning they **reflect a date as well as a *time of day***, so **using `-eq` to compare them to *calendar-day-only* time stamps**, as something like `[datetime]::Parse('2018-12-31')` would return<sup>[1]</sup>, **will *not* work as expected**.

To access just the *date* part (the very *start* of a calendar day) of a `[datetime]` instance, use the `.Date` property:

```
Get-ChildItem "$root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO" -Filter *.txt | 
  Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Date -eq [DateTime]::Parse($fecha) }
```

Note that since *nested* property access is needed, a *script block* must be used for the expression.

---

Of course, it's preferable to parse the user input as a string *beforehand*, to see if it represents a valid date: make sure that `$refDate = [DateTime]::Parse($fecha)` doesn't throw an exception; if so, re-prompt.

---

<sup>[1] Note that `[datetime]::Parse('<date-string>')` uses the *current* culture to parse the string, whereas `[datetime] '<date-string>'` would use the *invariant* culture.`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This would be the answer:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
Function Pick-Date {
  $Cal = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar
  $Cal.ShowWeekNumbers = $true
  $Cal.MaxSelectionCount = 1
  $Cal.Dock = 'Fill'
  $Form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
  $Form.text = "Colocar fecha que desea enviar. Y presiona Enter"
  $Form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(656,620)
  $btnSelect = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $btnSelect.Size = "100,100"
  $btnSelect.add_Click({ $Form.close() })
  $btnSelect.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(530,480)
  $btnSelect.Text="ENTER"
  $Form.Controls.Add($btnSelect )
  $Form.AcceptButton = $btnSelect
  $Form.Controls.Add($Cal)
  $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
  [void]$Form.ShowDialog()
  return (Get-Date($Cal.SelectionStart))
}

$fecha = Pick-Date

$archivos=Get-ChildItem "$root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\" -Filter *.txt | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Date -EQ $fecha}
```